# Select the filtered data in query-table through checkbox

Tags: ms-access-2013

I am trying to select (through a checkbox) all records which are filtered from "header column" of the access table. This is a table is generated from a query in form as "Source Object".

I have tried below codes, but this codes select all the records available in queried table.

I dont want to use query criteria for filtration. Kindly advise me if there is any way to accomplish this task.

I have tried below codes, but this codes select all the records available in queried table.

```
Private Sub Command452_Click()
Dim rst As Recordset, i As Integer, checkStat As String

Set rst = Me.RecordsetClone
i = 0
rst.MoveFirst
Do While Not rst.EOF
i = i + 1
rst.Edit
If rst![Select Channels] = True Then
  rst![Select Channels] = True
  checkStat = "Selected."
Else
   rst![Select Channels] = False
  checkStat = "Unselected."
End If
rst.Update
rst.MoveNext
Loop
MsgBox i & " Records " & checkStat

rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing

End sub
```

I don't want to use query criteria for filtration. Kindly advise me if there is any way to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes no sense - no updates here:

```
If rst![Select Channels] = True Then
  rst![Select Channels] = True
Else
   rst![Select Channels] = False
End If
```

and `checkstat` will just hold the value from the last record visited:

```
checkStat = "Unselected."
```

and **i** is just counting the records as they are looped.

And what does *filtered from "header column"* mean?

Comment: @ Gustav. Thanks for your response. I guess i was not clear to my request. Let me reframe it. There is a query result (in Table form) which is displayed on a form as "Source Object"

Comment: @ Gustav. Thanks for your response. I guess i was not clear to my request. Let me reframe it. There is a query result (in Table form) which is displayed on a form as subform/child form in "Source Object" Last column of table is checkbox & above code selects all records mentioned in table. What i want is - If i filter table through "Header" then i should be able to select the checkbox (available in last column of table) on that filtered records only instead of all records. Header Column means - First row of table with heading of records. checkStat is to tell no. of selected/Unselected records.

Comment: The `RecordsetClone` always returns the records currently displayed on its parent object (form). Thus, if the form is filtered, so will its RecordsetClone be.